# Problem getting dice roll program in c# working

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with a program in c# that requires a roll of a die. The amount of sides on the die is specified before the program is run and it displays the random value based upon the amount of faces. Relatively new to this topic and can't seem to get it to work. So far it looks like this:

```
public class Die
{
    public int die_faces  = 6;
    public int face_value = 1;

    public Die(int faces)
    {
        int die_faces = faces;
        RollDie();
        GetFaceValue();
        GetNumFaces();
    }
    public void RollDie()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        int face_value = rand.Next(die_faces);
    }
    public void GetFaceValue() =>  Console.WriteLine("current value of face: ", face_value);
    public void GetNumFaces()  => Console.WriteLine("current number of faces: ", die_faces);
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() => var myDie = new Die(7);
}
```

program runs and prints nothing for the values. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you assign values to new variables and for printing, you used class variables.
So please change the following two lines.

1. In constructor,`int die_faces = faces;` to `die_faces = faces;`
2. In RollDie() method, `int face_value = rand.Next(die_faces);` to `face_value = rand.Next(die_faces);`
3. Need to modify print with argument index as @KozhevnikovDmitry mentioned

   `Console.WriteLine("current value of face: {0}", face_value);`

   `Console.WriteLine("current number of faces: {0}", die_faces);`

If you are using c# 6 or later version, then you can use string interpolation as below to print.

`Console.WriteLine($"current value of face: {face_value}");`
`Console.WriteLine($"current number of faces: {die_faces}");`

so your final program will look like,

```
namespace DieRoller
{
    public class Die
    {
        public int die_faces = 6;
        public int face_value = 1;

        public Die(int faces)
        {
            die_faces = faces;
            RollDie();
            GetFaceValue();
            GetNumFaces();
        }

        public void RollDie()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            face_value = rand.Next(die_faces);
        }

        public void GetFaceValue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("current value of face: {0}", face_value);
        }

        public void GetNumFaces()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("current number of faces: {0}", die_faces);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
             Die myDie = new Die(7);
             Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to change the methods to be block-bodied. They were fine as expressions-bodied methods. Personally I'd use an interpolated string literal rather than a regular format string, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @Daisy thank you for your feedback. I didn't use string interpolation since I don't know which .net version is used. I will add it to the answer since it will add value to the answer.

Comment: String interpolation can be used with any version of .NET, so long as you're using a C# compiler that supports it - which the OP must be, as they're using expression-bodied members.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite `GetFacesVaue` and `GetNumFaces` in this way:

```
public void GetFaceValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("current value of face: {0}", face_value);
}

public void GetNumFaces()
{
    Console.WriteLine("current number of faces: {0}", die_faces);
}
```

Comment: The syntax isn't problem here. The OP is using *expression-bodied members*, introduced in C# 6 as a more concise syntax for writing simple method and property bodies. You've fixed the lack of `{0}` in the format string, and that *is* a fix, but there's no need to change the syntax being used.

Comment: As a side note, the more you *explain* what you've changed in the code and why, the more useful the answer will be. I initially didn't spot that you'd fix the format string, because the most obvious change was to the syntax you'd used. It would be great if you'd edit the answer now to explain what you've changed.

Answer (score -1):

A few things to note:

### You have to declare the variable before you can use and assign it, though you can declare and assign in the same line.

```
int number = 1;    // Creates a new int variable and assigns the value
number = 2;        // Reassigns number to now equal 2
anotherNumber = 3; // Doesn't work because we didn't declare the variable
```

If we have:

```
int field;

private void Foo()
{
    int field = 2;    // This creates a different field than the one at the top
}
private void Bar()
{
    field = 2;       // This works because it's the same field that's already been declared at the top
                     // It is NOT the same field that's used in Foo
}
```

So you should change your assignments of `die_faces` and `face_value` to not use `int` at the front.

### The `Console.WriteLine` is misformatted

Just because it's compiling, doesn't mean it's correct. You should change the code to be this:

```
public void GetFaceValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"current value of face: {face_value}");
}
```

Note, this will work too:

```
public void GetFaceValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("current value of face: {0}", face_value);
}
```

But it gets really confusing:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Health: {0}, Strength: {1}, Armor: {2}, Potions: {3}, Weapons: {4}", health, strength, armor, potions, weapons);
    // vs
    Console.WriteLine($"Health: {health}, Strength: {strength}, Armor: {armor}, Potions: {potions}, Weapons: {weapons}");
}
```

And you can use it anywhere:

```
string result = $"Health: {health}, Strength: {strength}, Armor: {armor}, Potions: {potions}, Weapons: {weapons}";
```

### Code that should work:

```
public class Die
{
    public int die_faces = 6;
    public int face_value = 1;

    public Die(int faces)
    {
        die_faces = faces;

        RollDie();
        GetFaceValue();
        GetNumFaces();
    }
    public void RollDie()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        face_value = rand.Next(die_faces);
    }
    public void GetFaceValue() => Console.WriteLine($"current value of face: ", face_value);
    public void GetNumFaces()  => Console.WriteLine($"current number of faces: ", die_faces);
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myDie = new Die(7);
    }
}
```

Note that `var die = new Die()` is the exact same as `Die die = new Die();` it's just less redundant and can often save time and space, `var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()` vs `Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()`

Comment: Your fixed version currently has the broken format string in `GetFaceValue` and `GetNumFaces`. You need to use the code from earlier in the answer :)